# How to pyparse with nested braces

Tags: python, nested, pyparsing, curly-braces

I've adapted my grammar from a similar problem but I'm unable to see what is wrong with my code.

Similar question: [PyParsing Parse nested loop with brace and specific header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23675372/pyparsing-parse-nested-loop-with-brace-and-specific-header)

My code with example:

```
    data = '''label key1=value1 keya=valuea
    {
        label key2=value2
        {
            key=value
        }
    }
    label key3=value3'''

    # I'm reusing the key characters for the header names, which can contain a semicolon
    VALID_KEY_CHARACTERS = srange("[a-zA-Z0-9_]")
    VALID_VALUE_CHARACTERS = srange("[a-zA-Z0-9_\"\'\-\.@]")

    lbr = Literal('{').suppress()
    rbr = Literal('}').suppress()
    eq = Literal('=').suppress()

    key = Word(VALID_KEY_CHARACTERS)
    value = Word(VALID_VALUE_CHARACTERS)
    label = Word(alphas)

    key_pair = Group(key + eq + value)("key_pair")
    header = label + Optional(OneOrMore(key_pair))

    expr = Forward()
    contents = Group(lbr + expr + rbr)("contents")
    expr << header + Optional(contents) + Optional(key_pair)

    result = expr.parseString(data).asList()
    pprint.pprint(result)
```

It is only returning this:

```
['label', ['key1', 'value1'], ['keya', 'valuea']]
```

Comment: Your innermost line `key=value` has no label, so it doesn't match the expression for `contents`.  You can add a label, or make the label optional and support a contents of one or more `key_pair` s by changing `contents` to `contents = Group(lbr + (OneOrMore(key_pair) | expr) + rbr)("contents")`, and that will parse your current example input.

Comment: Than you PaulMcG, this has been incredibly helpful.  I am struggling to find good resources of examples and this was insightful.

Comment: They could be better organized, but there are a number of examples in the pyparsing source examples directory. https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/tree/master/examples

Comment: Thanks Paul, don't get me wrong, great library and extremely powerful, thanks for your hard work.  I spent a day or two getting acclimated to it but it wasn't easy.